# Как подсветить полигон в google maps при клике на него?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Нужно сделать карту с возможностью добавления полигонов по клику на ней. Также при клике по полигону он должен подсвечиваться, а при клике на кнопку удалить - удаляться. 
Получилось что-то вроде такого

```
 addMarker: function (latLng, map) {
    var o = this.options;
    this.latLng = latLng;
    var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 3,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.2
        }
    });
     o.markers.push(newMarker);
     var vertexLat = +latLng.lat();
     var vertexLng = +latLng.lng();
     var vertex = {lat: vertexLat, lng: vertexLng};
     o.figureCoords.push(vertex);
},

 constructPolygon: function () {
    var o = this.options;
     this.newFigure = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: o.figureCoords,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        });
     }
```

Мы кликаем по карте, у нас создаются вершины, при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" у нас по сохраненным в массиве координатам отрисовывается полигон. Их может быть много на карте. Удалить все получается, но нужно сделать так, чтобы по клику на определенный полигон, он подсвечивался и появлялась возможность удалить именно его по клику на кнопку "удалить"

Answer (score 0):

```
        function selectFigure(event) {
            if (o.figureSelected === this) {
                o.figureSelected = {};
                this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.1,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.3});
            } else {
                !(Object.keys(o.figureSelected).length === 0) && o.figureSelected.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.1,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.3});
                o.figureSelected = this;
                this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.3,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5});
            };
        };
```

Удаление подсвеченного полигона

```
    deleteFigureSelected:function (map) {
        var o = this.options;
        clearFigureSelected();
        o.figureSelected = {};

        function setMapOnAllFigureSelected(map) {
            !(Object.keys(o.figureSelected).length === 0) && o.figureSelected.setMap(map);
        };

        function clearFigureSelected() {
            setMapOnAllFigureSelected(null);
        };
    },
```

Полностью код можно посмотреть тут https://github.com/EbenezerScrew/map-plugin